# jquery prototype conflict

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I inherited a project with a ton of old prototype. I'm trying to use jquery in noconflict mode but am getting error:

unterminated string literal.

Firebug points the error to prototype function toArray() {}

Somehow jquery or jquery ui is conflicting with prototype even though I am using jquery in noconflict mode.

Any ideas?

---- UPDATE - MY NOCONFLICT CODE ----

```
    <!-- the rest of these should will eventually be replaced with jquery and custom js in the agistix js dir -->
    <script src="/fs/scripts/lib/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="/fs/scripts/main.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />

    <script src="/fs/scripts/lib/prototype/prototype.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="/fs/scripts/validation.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fs/scripts/rsh.js?build=@buildtag@" />
    <script src="/fs/scripts/lib/scriptaculous/effects.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="/fs/scripts/lib/scriptaculous/controls.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="/fs/scripts/lib/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />

    <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script src="/fs/scripts/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js?build=@buildtag@" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: can you post your noconflict code

Comment: what about the `toArray` function?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a lot of trouble with minified versions of jquery, mootools and prototype. I'm not sure if this is related with the recent update strategy of some browser industry but I suggest you to try the uncompressed version of jquery.